# Как закрепить заголовок в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста как закрепить самую первую (0) строку в RecyclerView?
Есть самый простой List элементов, нужно чтобы самый первый элемент коллекции всегда оставался видимым, вне зависимости от скроллинга.

Comment: Похожая проблема решается [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112652/how-to-fixed-first-row-in-recyclerview-android). Либо используйте `Listview`, либо обновите layout как описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274519/android-how-to-avoid-header-from-scrolling-in-listview-android)

Comment: Там везде используется ListView, а вариант с выводом заголовка из RecyclerView как по мне костыль еще тот

Comment: Гляньте тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949971/how-can-i-make-sticky-headers-in-recyclerview-without-external-lib

Comment: ну так сделайте ваш заголовок отдельной вьюхой, а под ней ваш `recycler`

Comment: Так и сделал, другого варианта не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант решения данной проблемы - вынесение заголовка из RecyclerView. 
Второй вариант более сложный и в данном случае не имеющий смысла это создание так сказать "Липких" заголовков.